# calculate p-value for AFT survival model in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning

I am using Spark ml library to do some survival analysis. [Here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#survival-regression) is the documentation. After training an AFT survival model, I cannot get the p-value directly as in R. What is available for the model are a coefficients vector, scale, intercept, predictions and input data(Y and features). How can I use these variables to calculate p-value? Any advice is welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation, it looks like you cannot get the standard errors of the coefficients, or the values of the variance-covariance matrix of the negative information (Hessian) matrix, which is based on the second-partial derivatives of the log-likelihood w.r.t the coefficients.  Maybe they never wanted to provide those to users.